# Changing a value in the Path environment variable

Tags: powershell

My company uses a program that breaks when Java is updated.  This is due to the program install (I assume) placing a static path to Java in the Path environment variable.  For example, the current Path variable in question is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\client`, but if Java is updated and the program is re-installed, the Path variable will update to include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\client`.

I was able to find exactly what I needed (I think) here https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2007/11/08/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-remove-a-value-from-the-path-environment-variable/, but that code is for Powershell 2.0 and doesn't work on Windows 10.

Is this still possible in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `System.Environment` class to modify your environment variables machine-wide:

```
# get the PATH and split it up
$PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'Machine') -split ';'

# filter out the JRE paths
$PATH = $PATH -notmatch 'java\\jre'
# get any real JRE paths
$PATH += (Get-Item -Path "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Java\jre*\bin\client").FullName
$PATH = $PATH -join ';'

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $PATH, 'Machine')
```

Note: You will need to run your shell elevated to execute these commands.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, it splits up all the values of PATH, strips out the Java reference, then pieces PATH back together, right?  That would be perfect because I already know how to add values to PATH, but I couldn't find out how to remove one.

Comment: @Meecht Correct.  When you use the comparison operators against a *collection*, they act as *filters*.  It also adds the correct java path back to the PATH (`$PATH += ...`).

Answer (score 1):

Java is not a Windows issue, and therefore TechNet will not help you. There is a fix below.

Windows 10 and Windows 8:

- Open the *Legacy* Control Panel
- Click the *Advanced system settings* link.
- Click *Environment Variables*. In the section *System Variables*, find the *PATH* environment variable and select it.
- Click <kbd>Edit</kbd>.
- If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click *New*.
- In the *Edit System Variable* (or *New System Variable*) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable.
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- Close all remaining windows by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- Reopen the PowerShell window, and run your Java code.

Source: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: I'm not looking to run Java code.  I need to change a reference to the Java install location in the PATH environment variable.